# How to I restrict selection through based on a condition and display popup message for an error

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox

I am trying to create a sub-list from a master list based on checkbox checked by user in excel. I have created Form check box in macro and used a formula to create the list and I am unable to us validation on it.

I have 2 column, first column contain names and 2nd column contains 3 different categories and a checkbox to select the names. A total of 220 names are there spread between these 3 categories

For example Excel columns looks something like this:

```
ABC | Batsmen | checkbox    
XYZ | Batsmen | checkbox    
PQR | Bowler  | checkbox    
EST | WK      | Checkbox
```

checkbox mentioned here is Form Control checkbox from excel.
Once these checkbox is selected, the names and 2nd column should be copied in a different column and the list should be concatenating the new selections. I will select 11 out of 220 names.

Now these names have restrictions,
I cannot choose more than 4 Batsmen, 3 bowlers and 1 WK and If I have already selected 4 batsmen in my list, checkbox should not allow me to add more batsman and pop up an error message.

I tried using - Conditional Formatting, on click event macro but both this approach works only for manual entry and not through selection made through checkbox.

Comment: A print screen or a sample would help

Comment: File is attached in the dropbox link below,
D1:F191 contains Player details, Column F provides the checkbox to select. From players(column F2:F191) user can select only 11 Players and restriction will be based on Column E (BAT,BOWL,WK,ALL Rounder)
Example - out of total 11, Bat/Bowl/WK/ALL Rounder can be max 5,3,1,2 resp. These values are configurable through sheet - "Control File"
If user selects more than 5 BAT an error pop should stop them from selection

Please let me know if it made things clear.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/52x7yr3ls8319ka/IPL.xlsm?dl=0